# How do you write a function prototype in c++ that returns a structure?

Tags: c++, function-prototypes

I have to create a bisection program for quadratic equations. Here are the instructions for two individual steps:

The program has to meet the following requirements:

1. Coefficients a,b, and c of the quadratic equation shall be read from the keyboard by a separate function named `readCoeffs()`. The function shall return to the caller a structure with all 3 coefficients read. t can be 3 fields of a structure or a single field with a 3-element array.
2. Function, which calculates the roots, shall return the results to the caller in a form of a structure with 3 fields: root1, root2 and exists (a Boolean variable to determine if the roots exist).

I can't write the function prototypes and function headings correctly. When I write them like this:

```
struct calcRoots(double, double, double, double quadfunc(double), bool&);

struct readCoeffs();

int main(){
```

I get errors. I think Microsoft Visual Studio expects me I to create structures with curly brackets and a semicolon following. I am very lost. Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Here is the entire code I am working with. I am continually modifying it. This is my first course in c++. I am struggling.

```
/****************************************************************************
//File: bisect.cpp
//Finds the root of a function using the bisection method
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct coeffStru{
        double a;
        double b;
        double c;};
struct rootStru{
    double root1;
    double root2;
    bool exists;
               };

//function prototypes
struct calcRoots(double, double, double, double f(double),bool&);
double quadfunc(struct, double);
struct readcoeffs(coeffStru);

int main() {
    double xLeft=-10.0;
    double xRight=10.0; //end points of interval
    double epsilon;       //exists tolerance
    double root;          //root found by bisect
    bool exists;              //exists flag

//Get tolerance
cout<< "Enter tolerance: ";
cin>>epsilon;

struct coeffStru = readcoeffs();

//use bisect calcRoots function to look for root of function f
struct rootStru = calcRoots(xLeft, xRight, epsilon, quadfunc, exists);




//display result
if (!exists){
    cout<< "Root found at "<<root
        <<" \nValue of f(x) at root is: "<<f(root);
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
           }
else{
    cout<<"There may be no root in ["<<xLeft<<", "<<xRight<<"]"<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
    }
}




//Struct return type readcoeffs function
struct readcoeffs(coeffStru){

    cout<<"Enter values for a,b,and c of a quadratic equation."<<endl;
    cin>>a>>b>>c;
    return struct coeffStru;
                            }








//Implements bisection method to find a root of function f
//in interval [xLeft, xRight].
//PRE: xLeft, xRight, and epsilon are defined.
//POST: Returns midpoint of xLeft and xRight if the difference between thses values is <= epsilon. Returns true to exists if there is no root.
struct calcRoots (double xLeft, double xRight, double epsilon, struct coeffStru, double quadfunc(double), bool& exists) //IN: endpoints of interval for possible root, IN: exists tolerance, IN: the function, OUT: exists flag
{
    double xMid;                        //midpoint of interval
    double fLeft;
    double fRight;              //function values at xLeft, xRight,
    double fMid;                        //and xMid


//Compute function values at initial endpoints of interval
    fLeft = quadfunc(xLeft,coeffStru);
    fRight = quadfunc(coeffStru, xRight);


    //Repeat while interval > exists tolerance
    while (fabs ( xLeft - xRight) > epsilon)
    {
        //Compute function value at midpoint
        xMid = (xLeft + xRight)/ 2.0;
        fMid = quadfunc(coeffStru, xMid);

        //Test function value and reset interval if root not found
        if(fMid ==0.0)      //if xMid is the root
            root1 = xMid;    //set root1 to xMid
        else{ 
            xRight = xMid;
            xMid = (xLeft + xRight)/ 2.0;
            fMid = f(coeffStru, xMid);
            }
            if(fLeft * fMid < 0.0)  //root in [xLeft, xMid]





        //Display next interval
        cout<< "New interval is [" <<xLeft
            << ", " <<xRight << "]"<<endl;
    }    //ends 1st while loop


    //If no change of sign in the interval, there is no unique root
    exists = (fLeft * fRight) >0;  //test for same sign - set exists
    if(exists){ 
        return -999.0;      //no 1st root - return to caller
              }


    //Return midpoint of last interval
    root1 = (xLeft + xRight) / 2.0;
//Compute function values at initial endpoints of interval
    fLeft = f(coeffStru, xLeft);
    fRight = f(coeffStru, xRight);



    //Repeat while interval > exists tolerance
    while (fabs ( xLeft - xRight) > epsilon)
    {
        //Compute function value at midpoint
        xMid = (xLeft + xRight)/ 2.0;
        fMid = f(coeffStru, xMid);

        //Test function value and reset interval i root not found
        if(fMid ==0.0)      //xMid is the root
            return xMid;    //return the root
        else if (fLeft * fMid < 0.0)  //root in [xLeft, xMid]
            xRight = xMid;
        else                            //root in [xMid, xRight]
            xLeft = xMid;

        //Display next interval
        cout<< "New interval is [" <<xLeft
            << ", " <<xRight << "]"<<endl;
     }    //ends 2nd while loop


    //If no change of sign in the interval, there is no unique root
    exists = (fLeft * fRight) > 0;  //test for same sign - set exists
    if(exists){ 
        return -999.0;      //no 2nd root - return to caller
              }


    //Return midpoint of last interval
    root2 = (xLeft + xRight) / 2.0;

return struct rootStru;
}   //ends calcRoots method




//Function whose root is being found.
//PRE: x is defined.
//POST: Returns f (x)
double quadfunc(struct coeffStru, double x){
    return a * pow(x, 2.0) - b* pow(x, 1.0) + c;}


************************************************************/
```

I am getting many errors as you can imagine. My major issue now seems to be passing variables and structs by reference and values.

Comment: Post the code and error message, please !

Comment: Yes, the compiler will expect you to know some syntax. [Perhaps pick up a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: It sounds like you are jumping into a pool and you don't know how to swim. Start by learning the syntax first!

Comment: You've given the return type as `struct` -- but that doesn't specify _which_ `struct` is the return type. Have you already declared the `struct`s you'll be using? How many have you declared? How would the compiler know which one was going to be returned from each function? Why does your `calcRoots()` take a `quadfunc()` as an argument? Under what circumstances would you ever call `calcRoots()` with different functions?

Comment: @Jesse: This is how syntax is learned :) understanding error messages and warnings and maybe asking others for help when one can't figure out the fix ...

Comment: @sarnold There are many ways to learn. There are lots of other resources to exhaust first for the basics before you need to ask for help from an online forum ... would he understand the answer at this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct calcRoots(double, double, double, double quadfunc(double), bool&);
```

`struct` by itself is not a type. You should say the name of struct being returned. So, what kind of `struct` is `calcRoots` expected to return ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a two-step process:

(1) Define the struct that will hold the result, perhaps something like this:

```
struct ResultType {
    /* ... fields go here ... */
};
```

(2) Prototype the actual function:

```
ResultType calcRoots(double a, double b, double c, double function(double), bool& out);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
struct Coefficients
{
    double a, b, c;
};

struct Roots
{
    double root1, root2;
    bool exists;
};

Coefficients readCoeffs() { /* ... */ }

Roots calcRoots(const Coefficients& coefficients) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Structures in C++ are like structures in the C language.  You define them the same way.

```
struct coeff_t {
   double a;
   double b;
   double c;
};

struct roots_t {
    bool exist;
    double r1;
    double r2;
};
```

Now, with those definitions you can define your function prototypes:

```
coeff_t readCoeffs();

roots_t calcRoots( coeff_t & coeff );
```

Note the "&" preceding the coeff argument, that means passed by reference in C++, which means the compiler will pass the address, and know to dereference it inside the function, but you can just reference it as "coeff" within the function.